# How does this website work?

Tags: seo, web-development, wordpress, rss

By the looks of it [this website](http://www.hotelmarketing.com/) is just a feed of articles from other sites. How does it import the whole articles like this? and how is the site ranking at all with the lack on original content?

I am interested in finding out what would be involved with making a site similar to [Mashable](http://mashable.com/). I would want people to be able to login and add topics to their account, then the user has a feed of all the news for their topics. I was thinking of using Google news RSS feeds but I'm not sure. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the original content is not the strong feature of Google and other search engines. So, if you copy alien content from other websites and put it to yours and make link to your G+ account and submit your authorship, Google will identify you as the creator of it.

On http://www.hotelmarketing.com/ they add the link to the first source in the end of each article. This way they secure themselves from penalties.

> I was thinking of using Google news RSS feeds but I'm not sure.

You may use it without of being afraid, only add links to the original source.